# Perl: How to get the PID of the command executed using "make"

Tags: perl, makefile, pid

I have a Perl script, and in that script, I am executing the "make" command over the list of test cases. Now, I want to have the PID of each "make" command when it runs the test case so that I can monitor those PIDs.

Let's say, I have a test list

```perl
@array1 = ("/home/abc/test1/makefile", "/home/bcd/qwe/test2/makefile", "/home/PPP/makefile").
```

Now, when I run `make` on `/home/abc/test1/makefile`, I need the unique PID of this command (`make /home/abc/test1/makefile`).

Then, when I run `make` on `/home/bcd/qwe/test2/makefile`, I must get another unique ID, and similarly for other tests.

I would then use each PID to monitor for their time i.e. if a certain test executed using `make` (with a unique ID) reaches a time limit, then I would do something (that will be done via fork), but for that monitoring to happen, I would need the PIDs.

**Code Snippet which I am using:**

```
foreach my $i (@array1)
{
   my $filehandle;
   if ( ! open( $filehandle, "make $i 2>&1 |" ) ) {
       die( "Failed to start process: $!" );
   }
   else {
       print "Test started\n";
   }
   while ( defined( my $line = <$filehandle> ) ) {
       print( $line );
   }
}
```

How can I get the PIDs?

Comment: I believe the pid is returned by `open`.  `perldoc perlipc` and look for 'Using open'

Comment: So you want the PID of the external process that you run.  There are a number of ways to get that, and what you use is one of them: the "pipe open".  It does return the pid, so `my $pid = open my $pipe, '-|', @command;`

Comment: [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) supports timeouts, might be useful for you.

Comment: The problem here is that the `2>&1` is shell's, so whichever way the process is run it spawns the shell first, and that's the PID returned.,,

Comment: @zdim, Can you please explain what is the drawback of using "2>&1" here? And what if I remove it?

Comment: @zdim, I read them. Thanks! You can remove them.

Comment: @zdim, One more thing. How can I execute multiple commands (make; sleep 30) under open like: if ( $pid = ! open( $filehandle, "make $i; sleep 30 2>&1 |"). I tried this, but not working.

Comment: @PPP Yes, you string them together with `;` and put it under quotes.  I suggest the three-argument version: `my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', "make $i 2>&1; sleep 10; echo done" // die $!;`.  Note the `//` (defined-or) to test for success.  Read the docs.

Comment: @PPP Btw, I tested the above in a one-liner: `perl -we'my $pid = open my $fh, "-|", "ls -l | head; sleep 10; echo done"; print while <$fh>'`

Comment: @zdim, I am running this script on windows, and there "my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', "make $i 2>&1; sleep 10; echo done"  is not working. Just 1st command (make $i 2>&1) is working, and not sleep 10 and echo done

Comment: This is on windows? So ... there is no `sleep` on Windows, nor `echo` btw. (Unless you're under cygwin? I haven't used that in many years and I'm not sure whether all this can work on it and why it might not.)  But, I understand you want forks -- on Windows fork is emulated and I'd rather use threads.  (Even the piped-open itself forks so I don't know how that's done on Windows.) Or, better yet, figure out a way to set up libraries. I recall you said you couldn't (?) ... but one can probably even just copy files from CPAN and make it work. Can surely install as a user in your own folders.

Comment: @zdim, Yes, I am using cygwin sleep. When I am using my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', "make $i 2>&1; sleep 10; echo done", only make $i 2>&1 works. When I use my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', " sleep 10; make $i 2>&1; echo done", then only sleep 10 works. So, it means only 1st command is working and not what's written after.

Comment: @zdim, Thanks! one more clarification is needed. Will the environment variables set in the cmd will also go in the cmd open by "piped open"? Let's say, I have a variable ($abc="myVAR") set in main cmd from where script is launched. So, will this variable ($abc) will be accessible on the cmd opened by "piped open"?

Comment: [cont'd]  We  set up an environment variable in a Perl script by `$ENV{vV} = 'value';`, so using [`%ENV` hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25ENV).  Now a new, forked,  process sees `$vV` in its environment:  `perl -wE'$ENV{vV} = "hivV"; $pid = fork // die $!; if ($pid==0) { system("echo \$vV"); exit }; wait;'`.  So we run `echo` via Perl's `system` from the fork-ed process, and `hivV` is printed; the environment set up in the main process is inherited by the child.

Comment: The pipe-open forks a new process so the above applies. Is that what you need? I don't know :)

Comment: @PPP Done, removed.  I left a few earlier comments which are not "upvoted/liked", will see if you remove your questions then I will remove those as well (or we can just leave them)

Answer (score 3):

`open` returns the PID of the process it creates. But the process being created is running `sh`. The PID you should receive is the PID of the shell you're launching, not that of `make`.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you weren't trying to execute a shell command, you could use the "list form" of `open` to avoid the shell. But that's not available to you since you want to use the shell to perform redirection.

There are ways to address this will still using `open -|`, but it's far simpler to use IPC::Run, and it handles the timeout trivially.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );

run [ "make", $i ],
   ">",  \my $stdout,   # Or whatever
   "2>", \my $stderr,   # Or whatever
   timeout( 10 );

die( "make killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "make exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" ) if $? >> 8;

say "make successful.";
```

---

1. Perl sometimes optimizes the use of the shell away.

Comment: my system doesn't have IPC::Run, and I have restrictions to install it. Is there any other way?

Comment: What if I remove "2>&1" ? What's the significance of 2>&1 here?

Answer (score 2):

The `pid` of `make` is returned by `open`.  `perldoc -f open` states:

> ```
>         Open returns nonzero on success, the undefined value otherwise.
>         If the "open" involved a pipe, the return value happens to be
>         the pid of the subprocess.
> ```

Getting the `pid` of processes spawned by `make` is a different question, and will require more effort.

Comment: There's also a detailed discussion on that page under [Opening a filehandle into a command](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Opening-a-filehandle-into-a-command)

Comment: The problem is that `make` is not the subprocess, the shell is. `open` returns the pid of the shell running `make`, unless Perl optimizes the use of the shell away. (This can happen.) Best to use IPC::Run.

Comment: @ikegami Right, the only potential "problem" that I see is the PID, if one really needs it.  (Perhaps that could be stated somewhere on this page, but I am cleaning up my comments now since your answer showed it all )  Otherwise IPC::Run _is_ like a mini shell :)

Comment: @zdim, Re "*Otherwise IPC::Run is like a mini shell*",  That's the point. All the power of the shell, without having to deal with select()